# Accessing running Grails application from a remote machine

Tags: grails

I'm developing a Grails application to a school work. Typically, this is the URL for any server running on a local machine:

```
http://localhost:8080/ProjectName
```

After I run tomcat server with my Grails project, I go to that location and I can acess the website. But, as far as I know, everyone in my LAN should be able to load the website from same URL (`http://localhost:8080/ProjectName`). As I have two computers on same lan via router, I tried to acess my website and it doesnt seems to be working. How can access the application from another computer? If possible, suggest a website that I can read and learn stuff about this matter, cause my lack of knowledge about servers is so dramatic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use your machine's hostname or IP to access it from another machine.

You can get this information from a command prompt:

**Windows**

```
C:\>hostname
yourhostname

C:\>ipconfig
...
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.x.x
```

**Linux (usually)**

```
$ hostname
yourhostname

$ ifconfig
...
inet.addr:192.168.x.x
```

You can use either of those to get to it from another machine, e.g.

```
http://yourhostname:8080/YourApplication
```

or

```
http://192.168.x.x:8080/YourApplication
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want your local development instance to be available to other machines on your network, start grails like this:

> grails -Dgrails.server.host=0.0.0.0 run-app

Then you can get your own IP address from ipconfig or ifconfig as described in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6190980/311525).  You can then access your application from another machine.  Make sure your local firewall is not blocking 8080 (or whatever other port you've decided to start grails on)