# How to run Grails application so that other computers on network can access it?

Tags: grails, networking, localhost, ip-address, ipv4

I've developed a Grails application and I want my coworkers to be able to test it. They are on my network so I figure they can access it by using my IP address and the port number (8080). I've tried running it according to the steps laid out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190929/accessing-running-grails-application-from-a-remote-machine) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623661/make-grails-listen-on-external-ip-address) to no avail.

I noticed that whenever I run the program, even when I follow those instructions, it says:

> Grails application running at http://localhost:8080 in environment: development

Comment: Depending on your version of grails - there was a bug where it would alway show localhost even though it is listening on the correct IP

Comment: This is possible. I'm using Grails 3.0.8.

Answer (score 1):

Basic networking stuff here.

When something starts on interface 127.0.0.1 port something

Usually that port is then available for all the interfaces on the machine

if you run `netstat -plant` you will see running ports open on the machine.

Basically what ever ipconfig or `ifconfig` tells under Linux  as your internal interface something like `192.168.1.x`

The app is then available on `http://192.168.1.x:8080`

If you can't access it from other machines on network start by trying to `ping {your machine ip}`

It sounds like network security stopping local access from 1 machine accessing another.

Or even better still your good old MS firewall try stopping your security stuff on your desktop

Comment: I've tried to ping the other machines and tried to ping my machine using theirs; it all works fine. I'm thinking it might be a bug with my grails as someone else has mentioned or a firewall issue.

Comment: telnet ip 8080  or use netcat to test port connection after ping https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-netcat-to-establish-and-test-tcp-and-udp-connections-on-a-vps . if you can't get through and can ping quite likely to be firewall - stop the windows firewall on the desktop and try it hardly something that should take this long

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot stop the firewall as it is against policy. Any other solutions? I've looked into using Tomcat and deploying the war file.

Comment: How about researching how you can add a rule to your firewall to allow local subnet through to port 8080 of your machine. This is really spoon feeding. You should step back and think what is a firewall what is it doing what needs to be done instead

Comment: It's not a firewall issue. If I run Tomcat at the localhost then other machines are able to access it, so it's a problem with grails.

Comment: So, the first question still stands.

Comment: no idea what you mean, a bug in your grails application ? you can access it locally, You can't access it from another machine on the network. That is a grails bug lol oh my. Who ever has suggested to you that you can't disable firewalls is the person you need to speak to in your organisation and explain the problem you are having aka the networks team.

Comment: Install APACHE run it on port 8080 can you access it on the other machine or is there also a bug with apache too ? :)

Comment: I work for a government agency and they're very strict about their firewall policies. They suggested I use apache tomcat, which was my next plan anyway. I already said I installed apache, ran it on port 8080 and it noted it was accessible locally and via other machines. So the previous issue I had where it wasn't accessible, correct me if I'm wrong, seems to be a grails issue.

Comment: well I use 3.10 and I have no such issue so try a test app under 3.0.8 and 3.10 see if that makes a difference. At the end of the day you need to try things at your end till it works whether it is a bug in the specific 3.0.8 or not.  you could always packge it up as war and run it in a local tomcat. I don't think you can do grails run-war on 3.0.8 that be another alternative.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you can access the app yourself on your own machine? It should be available at:

```
http://localhost:8080/appname
```

Your co-workers should be able to access the app by changing localhost to your computer name:

```
http://mycomputername:8080/appname
```

Comment: I can access it fine on my machine, but my coworkers cannot using the method you mentioned; it's already been tried.